# AppVeyor: Build Failed : Cant locate NUnit assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0, appveyor

I'm having trouble building these simple tests using NUnit. Project passes the build using MStest, but as soon as I switch to NUnit it fails the build.

The error I'm getting during build process is basically:

> **Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If
>   this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation
>   errors.**

I have NUnit 3.5 downloaded from NUGET and added the .dll to my references, and still nothing. I also have also made sure the properties of that reference have the copy local property set to true.

Here is my build log URL on AppVeyor (https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ReevMich/traviscitest/build/1.0.26)

This is my `appveyor.yml` contents if that helps.:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - dev

configuration: Debug

before_build:
  - nuget restore 

build:
  verbosity: minimal
  project: FizzBuzz.sln

test:
  assemblies:
    - '**\*.Test.dll'
artifacts:  
- path: '**\*.nupkg'
  name: NuGet
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `packages` folder from your repository ([it doesn't contain assemblies anyway](https://github.com/ReevMich/traviscitest/tree/master/packages/NUnit.3.5.0/lib/net45)), so it's always re-created during the build with `nuget restore`.

Comment: Thank you!, gah it's always something so small.